# Javascript Binary Search algorithm unable to find number in the list

Tags: javascript, binary-search

The following code seems to be unable to find the number in the list. Why might this be?

Trying this with the number to search for as '9' and the array of numbers consisting of numbers between 1-10 inclusively.

```js
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
count = 0;

function binarySearch(array, number) {
    mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    if (number === array[mid]) {
        return count;
    }

    else if (number < array[mid] && array.length > 1) {
        count++;
        arrayFirst = array.splice(0, array[mid]);
        console.log("Tried: ", array[mid])
        console.log(arrayFirst);
        return binarySearch(arrayFirst, number);
    }

    else if (number > array[mid] && array.length > 1) {
        count++;
        arraySecond = array.splice(array[mid], array.length);
        console.log("Tried: ", array[mid])
        console.log(arraySecond);
        return binarySearch(arraySecond, number);
    }

    else {
        return 'number doesnt exist';
    }


}
console.log(binarySearch(array, 4));
```

The code is now struggling with finding the number 10
New Edit:

```js
       array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    count = 0;
    
    function binarySearch(array, number) {
        mid = Math.floor(array.length/ 2);
        if (number === array[mid]) {
            return count;
        }
    
        else if (number < array[mid] && array.length > 1) {
            count++;
            arrayFirst = array.splice(0, mid);
            console.log("Tried: ", array[mid])
            console.log(arrayFirst);
            return binarySearch(arrayFirst, number);
        }
    
        else if (number > array[mid] && array.length > 1) {
            count++;
            arraySecond = array.splice(array[mid], mid);
            console.log("Tried: ", array[mid])
            console.log(arraySecond);
            return binarySearch(arraySecond, number);
        }
    
        else {
            return 'number doesnt exist';
        }
    
    
    }
    
    console.log(binarySearch(array, 10));
```

Comment: Your condition includes an undefined variable `arr`... It's called `array`

Comment: Yes, I spotted that too just now, thank you!

Comment: look at the index,  when you do ´Math.floor(array.length/ 2)´ you get 10 but array[10] it the 11th element

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
array = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
```

is not an array, it's interpreted as a list of initialization, like this:

```
 array = 1, x = 2, y = 3...;
```

and so your `array` is just `1`, and not the entire list. Also keep in mind that **it is Not Recommended to declare a variable without var keyword. It can accidently overwrite an existing global variable.** Instead you should use `var`, `let` or `const` based on the use of that variable

Instead, this should be your array:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Comment: aha! silly error, thank you I am new to Javascript! :)

Comment: no problem, i've added a little bit of explanation. @Marcooz2007

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers here:

- Your condition includes an undefined variable `arr`. You've  been using `array`.
- Your array must be `array = [1,2,3]`
- I would suggest to instantiate your variables `arrayFirst, mid, arraySecond` as const `const mid = ...` so they are block scoped and not global vars

Edit: Looks like you've modified your `arr` condition. Please avoid edits as it makes answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes:

- Take counting inside of the function by returning either one or zero or one plus the result of the call with a sub array.
- Check length in advance (spelling matters ... `arr`) and return zero for unrachable values.
- **Use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (prevent mutation) and take the index, not the value of the item.**
- Finally return one plus the count of left or right side.

```js
function binarySearch(array, number) {
    console.log(...array);
    var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  
    if (number === array[mid]) return 1;
    if (array.length <= 1) return 0;

    return number < array[mid]
        ? 1 + binarySearch(array.slice(0, mid), number)
        : 1 + binarySearch(array.slice(mid), number);
}

console.log('count:', binarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `array.splice(0, array[mid])`

`array[mid]` is the value in the array and you need the quantity of elements to subtract `array.splice(0, mid)`  [splice docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)

also index start from 0 so your `array[mid]` is taking the 6th element and not the middle.